# instanceof cannot be used with any class?

Tags: java, inheritance, compiler-errors, extends, instanceof

I am trying `instanceof` in Java. I declared three classes where one extends another as follows:

```
class ParentClass {
    // Class members
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    // Class members
}
class OtherClass {
    // Class members
}
```

`instanceof` works fine if it will give true as in the first three usages below. However, it gives *"Incompatible conditional operand types error"* when used with a class that will give false in the last statement:

```
public class JavaTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildClass childObj = new ChildClass();
        System.out.println(childObj instanceof ChildClass);
        System.out.println(childObj instanceof ParentClass);
        System.out.println(childObj instanceof Object);
        System.out.println(childObj instanceof OtherClass);
    }
}
```

What is the reason for that?

Comment: `childObj` can _never_ be an `OtherClass`, completely independent hierarchies.

Comment: So, what is its usage if it will always give true? When will it give false? I think I am misusing it.

Comment: @OsamaEl-Ghonimy `ChildClass c = null; System.out.println(c instanceof ChildClass);` will print false.

Comment: @OsamaEl-Ghonimy also `System.out.println(childObj instanceof List);` will compile but print `false`.

Comment: The compiler will reject it if it **knows** the check will always return `false`.

Comment: @OsamaEl-Ghonimy The type is known, `ChildClass` can *never* be `OtherClass`. But consider the case when the variable `childObj` is `Object`.

Comment: not allowed by Java Language Specification [15.20.2. The instanceof Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2): "**The RelationalExpression must be checked cast compatible with the ReferenceType (§5.5), or a compile-time error occurs.**" (original empahsis) || If you really must test it, you can do `(Object)childObj instanceof OtherClass`

Answer (score 4):

The compiler knows at compile time that `childObj instanceof OtherClass` will never be true so the compiler fails fast and rejects the code.

You could declare `childObj` as `Object` instead and it should compile.

For example:

```java
Object childObj = new ChildClass();
System.out.println(childObj instanceof OtherClass);
```